# Python seems to treat instance variable as a class variable

Tags: python, oop

I have an instance variable that seems to be treated like a class variable since it changes all instances of the object.

```
class DNA(object):

      def __init__(self,genes = pd.DataFrame(), sizecontrol=500, name='1'):
        self.name = name
        self.genes = genes  # This attribute should be an instance variable 
        self.GeneLen = self.genes.shape[1]
        self.sizecontrol = sizecontrol
        self.Features = []
        self.BaseFeats = []
        random.seed(self.name)
```

When I run this I get the following:

```
 In[68]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

 In[69]: x1 = DNA(genes=df)

 In[70]: x2 = DNA(genes=df)

 In[71]: x1.genes["dummy"] = 'test'

 In[72]: x2.genes["dummy"].head(4) 
 Out[72]:   
  0 test 
  1 test 
  2 test 
  3 test
```

How can I make sure x1.genes does not affect x2.genes?

Comment: Try passing the df variable as `DNA(genes=df.copy())`

Comment: Both your instances are using the same dataframe as their `.genes` attribute.

Comment: Where @PM2Ring means literally the same object in memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two issues here.

First, data frames are mutable objects and both of your instances are referencing the same object. You'll want to supply a new copy to each instance using `df.copy()`. You could alternatively copy the dataframe in the `__init__` function itself. This would be "safer" in that can be sure that you are not reusing data frames, but this also might create unnecessary copies.

Second, and not relevant in your example, there is an issue with supplying a mutable default argument, `genes = pd.DataFrame()`. This data frame is saved on the unbound `__init__` function like it was member data of that function (see `__init__.__func__.func_defaults`). Instead, use a default argument of `None` or some other sentinel value and then instantiate a new data frame when `genes is None`.

Comment: "This data frame is saved on the class sort of like member data of the class" Not exactly, but I know what you mean. It's just that default args are evaluated once, when the class definition itself is created. And that's why it can lead to problems with default mutable args.

Comment: @SyrtisMajor That's not really relevant to the OP's question since they aren't actually using that default arg. But I fully agree that _if_ they want a default there, they should be using `None` and testing for `None` in the body of the `__init__`

Answer (score 5):

Your code is working fine in the sense that `genes` is an attribute of instances of the `DNA` class.

However, you only ever created one dataframe. You assign the name `df` to it and also make it the attribute `genes` of both `x1` and `x2` with the

```
self.genes = genes
```

assignment. Since **assignment never copies data** you still have only one dataframe which is shared across `x1` and `x2`.

[image]

To solve the issue, you could either make a copy of your dataframe before passing it to the `DNA` constructor or use

```
self.genes = genes.copy()
```

in the `__init__` method.